# Jquery-DataTables catch search event but not those from ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am rendering a graph of the data in the Jquery DataTables table and would like to trigger a function to re-draw the graph upon a change in the table contents from the UI search OR calling a search such as below

```
$('#mytable').DataTable().column(0).search('my value').draw()
```

on my table I have the following code

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    //my settings here
}).on( 'search.dt',   function () { updateGraph( GraphData ) ; } );
```

The code is working but on a sort event, such as ordering a column a search followed by an order event is triggered. Is there a way to trigger a change only when the table contents change?

see this example for further information.
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dt_events.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a good catch! Never realized that the `search.dt` event was triggered even on simple ordering. A peculiar issue actually. Perhaps other people will come up with a better idea, but I think keeping a "snapshot" of the current rows and compare them to the rows when `search.dt` is triggered could solve the problem. If the `snapshot` is based on the table rows default order, or `index`, not by the applied ordering, then we could trigger a `datachange.dt` event if and only if data actually has changed within the dataTable :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   snapshot: null
})
.on('search.dt', function() {
  var snapshot = table
     .rows({ search: 'applied', order: 'index'})
     .data()
     .toArray()
     .toString();

  var currentSnapshot = table.settings().init().snapshot;

  if (currentSnapshot != snapshot) {
   table.settings().init().snapshot = snapshot;
   if (currentSnapshot != null) $('#example').trigger('datachange.dt')
  }
})
.on('datachange.dt', function() {
  alert('data has changed')
  //updateGraph( GraphData )
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hftuew5u/**

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it solves my problem exactly. I assume the processing overhead is low or at least lower than my call to my updateGraph function to update my graph. That is the original intention to distinguish between an order and a "search" event to limit the need to call the function update without a change to the actual data irrespective of the order.

Comment: @David, Thank you for accepting. I understand the concern, was also considering this.  But think about it, if you have a paginated table with perhaps 20 columns, 500 rows and an average content of 20 chars per column it will be 195kb dynamic data, that is within the reasonable.  It will not slow down rendering of the page, at "best" a 1-2 ms delay before the datachange event is triggered, so I think it is ok. ..But as everything else, only a real live scenario can be the judge...

Comment: thanks for the back of the envelope estimate. For my application the delay for update graph appears much slower than entering just an order event which triggers a search. The solution worked out of the box, only requiring editing the '#example' to my page's '#mytable'.

Comment: @David, has raised it as an issue -> https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/953 in my opinion the behaviour you discovered is a "blunder", it is not logical. There should be a distinction between the events and the actions that is triggering the events.

Comment: Copying  reply from primary developer,                                           "Actually, this is technically correct as DataTables does do a filter when sorting is applied to the table.

This is the line of code that triggers that. The _fnReDraw function will trigger both order and search.

The reason it is done this way is that the order is applied to the entire data set, and then rather than also applying the sort to the filtered data set, it applies the filter again. It would need to be one or the other - neither optimal perhaps, but this is the way I've chosen to implement it."

Comment: @David, I think the answer is "wrong". I am full aware of how the code works, it  should just work different. I have made a lot of contributions to dataTables, but this includes the core, beyond my scope.